# Low quality picture produced by snapshot. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

The program below creates a snapshot with the content of the main window of the application itself. However the quality of the produced picture is not equivalent to the print screen program of windows 10, which produces the desired result.

Here is a snapshot of the program running, taken with the print screen program of windows 10, zoomed in:

https://ibb.co/wz4pb4d

And here is the snapshot that the program below is producing, zoomed in:

https://ibb.co/DLsNb8X

Is there something we can try to improve the quality of the snapshot that this program produse?

I tried Bitmap Encoder but is the same result , just without transparency, (Don't need to have transparency) also tried some other Pixel Formats but I get errors, only Pbgra32 seems to work as the program is.

```
        if (e.Key == Key.P)
        {
            //Set scrollviewer's Content property as UI element to capture full content
            UIElement element = mainwindow.Content as UIElement;
            Uri path = new Uri(@"C:\Users\4gry\Desktop\screenshot.png");
            CaptureScreen(element, path);
        }

    }
        public void CaptureScreen(UIElement source, Uri destination)
        {
            try
            {
                Double Height, renderHeight, Width, renderWidth;

                Height = renderHeight = source.RenderSize.Height;
                Width = renderWidth = source.RenderSize.Width;

                //Specification for target bitmap like width/height pixel etc.
                RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)renderWidth, (int)renderHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                //creates Visual Brush of UIElement
                VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(source);

                DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
                using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
                {
                    //draws image of element
                    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(Width, Height)));
                }
                //renders image
                renderTarget.Render(drawingVisual);

                //PNG encoder for creating PNG file
                PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(destination.LocalPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    encoder.Save(stream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }



}
```

}

Comment: Just a thought: can you try using `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` instead of `RenderSize.Height` and `RenderSize.Width`? I think the quality is lost not on the encoding, but because WPF is doing some subpixel rendering, which makes me believe that you're not giving the right size

Comment: @KevinGosse RenderSize is usually identical to ActualWidth/Height.

Comment: I replaced RenderSize.Width and height with ActualWidth \ height, same result...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you can avoid anti-aliasing effects by setting the `RenderOptions.EdgeMode` property of the source element to `EdgeMode.Aliased`.

Note also that you can also write your CaptureScreen method somewhat simpler:

```
public void CaptureScreen(UIElement source, string destination)
{
    RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(source, EdgeMode.Aliased); // here

    var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
            new VisualBrush(source),
            null,
            new Rect(source.RenderSize));
    }

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)Math.Round(source.RenderSize.Width),
        (int)Math.Round(source.RenderSize.Height),
        96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

    bitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

    using (var stream = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create))
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

In order to create an image with a higher resolution, use a DPI parameter instead of the default 96 like this:

```
public void CaptureScreen(UIElement source, double dpi, string destination)
{
    RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(source, EdgeMode.Aliased);

    var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
            new VisualBrush(source),
            null,
            new Rect(source.RenderSize));
    }

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)Math.Round(source.RenderSize.Width * dpi / 96),
        (int)Math.Round(source.RenderSize.Height * dpi / 96),
        dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Default);

    bitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

    using (var stream = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create))
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Something is slightly changed by setting the RenderOptions.EdgeMode... it became little sharper, but it's far from the desired result, Thank you

Comment: You may create the bitmap at a higher DPI than 96. Just scale the bitmap size appropriately, as shown in the second part of the answer.

Comment: When I transfer your code to the program and paste it below the keydown handler, The ''CaptureScreen'' become underlined red and say:

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'destination' of Mainwindow.CaptureScreen(UIElement, double, string)

Comment: Well, basic C# again. Call `CaptureScreen(element, 300, @"C:\Users\4gry\Desktop\screenshot.png");`

Comment: In many pieces of screenshot code, I see them using Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(source) to set the new Rect(new Point(), bounds.Size)) within DrawRectangle, is there a difference between that and you calling new Rect(source.RenderSize)?